# How should you encode VSE output so that it will play correctly in Windows Media Player?

Tags: export, video-sequence-editor, video

I can't for the life of me figure this out. I've tried so many different combinations of video containers, formats, and codecs and none of them have worked. Is there ANY possible way that you can output a VSE video so that it will play in Windows Media Player in Windows 10?

My video is about 5 minutes of compiled 4K clips (with audio), which was originally encoded in H.264 and was originally in the .MOV format. I can view it just fine in Windows Media Player. I made a montage in Blender Video Sequence Editor, and everything works great, but I cannot properly render, encode, and export it so that I can watch it on Windows Media Player or any other native Windows application. I've tried lots of different combinations of codecs and formats, none have worked. Which combination should work with Windows Media Player?

I've tried downloading codec packs for Windows 10, but every time I do, it seems to make me unable to play the .MOV videos my camera card puts out, which is very important because I need to be able to review assets before I can put them into my video.

[image]

Comment: which version of windows media player do you have? Only the 12th one supports .mov https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/316992 Have you tried VLC player? Its free and better

Comment: I've got version 12. I've tried VLC and it's choppy and horrible, with lots of gigantic artifacts. I also want my video to play in the native Windows 10 Photos App (or Movies and TV) because it's got a very nice UI. From what I've seen, if it works in Windows Media Player it will work in Photos.

Comment: what are the dimensions/resolution/frame rate in blender? 4k isnt a preset so you must have manually typed it in

Comment: I set it to 3840 x 2160 (x100%) at 30 FPS, which is the same as how it was recorded.

Comment: im drawing a blank, maybe you can upload a snip-bit so I can try different settings too, I have windows media player too.

Comment: How would I do that? I can't exactly just upload the blend file because it'd probably be around 20 gigs.

Comment: right click on a video(smaller the better) click "rename" and switch it from .mov to .mp4 Then upload it to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ That way I can download it and switch it back to .mov